# Fire ColdFusion function on Change of Select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, forms, coldfusion

I am not sure the best way to accomplish the following process: I have an invoke statement that I want to change one of the arguments depending on the value of a select dropdown.

Below is my code so far:

```
<label>Filter by Status: </label>
    <select>
        <option value="not_assigned">Waiting to be Assigned</option>
        <option value="assigned">Assigned</option>
        <option value="returned">Returned</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    </select>



    <cfinvoke component="RFQ.cfc.data" method="adminrfqList" returnvariable="adminrfqListReturn">
             <cfinvokeargument name="statusVal" value="CHANGE THIS BASED ON SELECTION ABOVE">
    </cfinvoke>
```

I know JQuery and ColdFusion can communicate with `#toScript` I am just not sure the best way to accomplish my task.

Below is how I have used #toScript in the past:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    <cfoutput>
    var #toScript(ReBuild, "jsVar")#;
    </cfoutput>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var id = window.location.href.match("(ID=|id=|/)[0-9]+")[0].match("[0-9]+");
    $('form').loadJSON(jsVar);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: No, jQuery and ColdFusion CANNOT communicate with `toScript()`. ColdFusion is server side, jQuery is client side. The only way you can get them to communicate is by using AJAX requests.

Comment: I posted how I have used toScript in the past which my not be communication but it does let them work together in some sense.

Comment: What if the select dropdown was a cfselect? Would that allow me to update the value of the invoke argument? I am a coldfusion novice so I am just learning its limits and strong points.

Comment: Don't use `cfselect` (or any of the ColdFusion UI functionality), learn how to do this the right way.

Comment: All `toScript()` is doing there is creating a JavaScript (client side) variable that has the same structure as a ColdFusion variable that is passed. Once the JS variable is created, it no longer has anything to do with ColdFusion, it is all client side at that point. You are mistaken if you think that allows jQuery and ColdFusion to 'communicate'.

Comment: Scott I appreciate your feedback and your direction "learn to do it the right way" which is how I normally like to do stuff. If you could explain what the right way is I would be much appreciative.

Comment: Use jQuery to set up event listener on the select box and then in the listener, fire off an AJAX request to the server. If you want specific details about any  of these steps, try searching for the answer, you will probably find answers on StackOverflow

Comment: +1 to what Scott said. If you Google "coldfusion select jquery," the first result is a StackOverflow post on how to do this.